# Outlook - 0×8004010F Error thrown on accessing mounted mailbox

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mapi

0×8004010F Error is thrown when one user access the mailbox of another mounted user in outlook. What could be the possible resolution for this, other than disabling cached exchange mode? VSTO is used and the implementation is in C#.

Comment: For reference 0x8004010F = MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the way we were handling the COM object. Inadvertently, We made the COM Object, which is shared by Outlook,  null on the exceptional cases. Fixed it.

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

I have found excellent solution for this error, here: [Exchange Error 0x8004010f](http://outlook-exchange-server-errors.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-solve-exchange-error-0x8004010f.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND.
What line of your code throws that error?